# Change the value of only the first matching object in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I take values from a user, store them in an object as properties, and store them in an array. The array consists of the following:

```
[
  #<Tender:0x0000000001edc870 @company_name="a", @cost=20, @note="dfgv", @rejection_reason="", @status="open">,
  #<Tender:0x0000000001edb088 @company_name="b", @cost=15, @note="dfg", @rejection_reason="", @status="open">
]
```

I have two methods: `accept_tender` and `reject_tender`. `reject_tender` stores `'rejected'` in `@status`. `accept_tender` stores `'accepted'` in `@status`. The output will be something like this:

```
Companies     Cost       Status      Reason for rejection 
AA            240000     rejected      cost is high 
BB            200000     accepted       
CC            230000     closed
```

The third status will be changed to `'closed'`, once `accept` method is called. The code for `accept` method is as follows:

```
def accept_tender
  project_data = find_project
  if project_data.nil?
    puts 'No such project'
  else
    minimum_cost = @tender_management.tenders.map { |tender| tender.cost }.min
    company_data = @tender_management.tenders.map { |tender| [tender.company_name, tender.cost] }.flatten!
    company_name = company_data [company_data.index(minimum_cost) - 1]
    puts "Selected tender is of cost #{minimum_cost} of company #{company_name}"
    update_status
    Menu.show_menu(self)
  end
end

def update_status
  @tender_management.tenders.find { |tender|
    tender.status = 'accepted' if tender.status == 'open'
  }
  @tender_management.tenders.find { |tender|
    tender.status = 'closed' if tender.status == 'open'
  }
end
```

I used the `find` method to find the first status which is `'open'` and then change it to `'accepted'`. Once this is done, all remaining `'open'` status should be changed to `'closed'`. Is there any other way than using `find`?

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Does it behave incorrectly? Or just academic interest about possible ```find``` replacement?

Comment: No the given code works properly. I am just new to Ruby and hence want to explore more methods. Is there any replacement possible?

Comment: If your intent is to change *all* remaining "open" statuses to "closed", you probably should not use `find` in the second block of `update_status`, right? Doesn't this only update the next "open" status, not *all* of them? You could use `each` instead of `find` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to the above question.Apart from `find`, one can also use the `detect` method to change only the first occurrence of an instance in an array.